# Requested permission for Facebook share_open_graph (video.rates action)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer, facebook-permissions

Which permissions do I have to request, in Facebook Sumbit Review, to use this code?

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'video.rates',
    action_properties: {
        "rating:value": 9,
        "rating:scale": 10,
        "review_text": "Beautiful movie",
        "movie": "http://moovote.com/#!/movie/0109830"
    }
}, function (response) {});
```

- publish_actions ?
- user_actions.video ?
- Rate open graph action ?

Comment: Fixed some grammar, removed irrelevant thanks

Comment: You need to get your use of that action approved.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you don't need any of those permissions at all if you're using the standard share dialog, as said at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

> The Share dialog prompts a person to publish an individual story or an Open Graph story to their timeline. **This does not require Facebook Login or any extended permissions, so it is the easiest way to enable sharing on web.**

Comment: I tried it without permissions but it returns an error:
error_code: 100
error_message: "App+xxxxxxxxx+is+not+allowed+to+create+actions+of+type+video:Rate+for+user+xxxxxxxxx"

I asked it in Facebook Bug Support and a Facebook developer answers:
"your OG stories is not approved yet which means only admins, developers , testers of the app can use it."

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/877084542353980/

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't mean that there's a problem with the permissions. Just test it with an admin/tester/developer of your app. If there's still a problem I guess FB's docs are inconcise...